# Playing Animation before Rendering neccessary?

Tags: rendering

Do I have to play my animation from beginning to end (starting at frame 0)before rendering it?
Because if I do not the simulation I use (cloth) doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must. Simulation and animation is not the same. You must bake simulations before rendering. I highly recommnend using bake button in simulation properties instead play animation button in timeline.